# Mini video player for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, video, media-player

I want a tiny little video player without the windows borders and stuff like that that sits in the corner and plays videos.

Like this Android YouTube or VLC player that has a feature to play videos on top in the corner:

[image]

<sup>image source: [How to Watch YouTube in the Background on Android](https://www.labnol.org/internet/background-youtube-android/27046)</sup>

Something like that but for Windows.

It should the following features:

- be without borders, title bar, etc. It should just play frame-less video
- resizable
- always on top (as an option)
- snap to screen borders and the Taskbar
- drag to move
- drag-and-drop videos into the player to play them
- usual keyboard controls (play/pause/stop, next/prev, fast-forward/backward)
- gratis

Optional features:

- playlist support
- play YouTube videos (lot of desktop playes are able to do this nowadays, like VLC, MPC-BE)

Comment: Always on top? Drag to relocate on screen?

Answer (score 1):

[VideoPlayer](https://tomeko.net/software/VideoPlayer/), binaries packed with mplayer: [VideoPlayer_2_3_0.7z](https://github.com/tomek-o/VideoPlayer/releases/download/v2.3.0/VideoPlayer_2_3_0.7z).

Seems to fit description quite precisely, with exceptions for snapping to screen borders and youtube support.
Default hotkey configuration is close to one used by mplayer (which also almost fits description, but there would be few inconveniences like not remembering size/position).